# A proper and surjective map so that it transforms a set of linear functions into a monomial

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, optimization

I'm studying [sequential optimality conditions](http://www.ime.unicamp.br/%7Emartinez/ahm.pdf). The sequential optimally conditions I am using requires to solve a linear system of equations to prove the equivalence between two of them. Luckily, it's easy to solve this linear system whenever the functions involved in the problem can be written as monomials, see the [introduction and definitions therein](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1990-317-02/S0002-9947-1990-0943608-5/). In this context, since everything can be reduced to a finite set of linear functions $f_i: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, it would be good to know a version of the desingularization theorem, see [Theorem 2.1.](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1990-317-02/S0002-9947-1990-0943608-5/S0002-9947-1990-0943608-5.pdf), for a set of linear functions $f_i: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ without refering to the toric desingularization needed. Hence, my question reduces to:

> Is there a version of the Theorem 2.1. in which it has an easy-to-follow proof for a finite set of linear functions $f_i: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? That is, let $\mathscr F$ be a finite set of non trivial real-valued linear functionals $f_i: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I would like to know if it's possible to guarantee a simple proof for finding a desingularization $(N,\theta,\nu)$ of $\mathscr F$ such that $\nu$ has full rank.

Theorem 2.1:

> Let $\mathscr F$ be a finite set of non trivial real-valued real-analytic functions on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then $\mathscr F$ has a toric desingularization $(N,\theta,\nu)$ such that $\nu$ has full rank.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what's going on here. What does it mean to have a linear function on a real-analytic manifold?

Comment: I forgot to say that my manifold $M$ is a vector space. Is the description of the problem better now?

Comment: I mean, maybe I'm misinterpreting the problem rather horribly, but it would seem to me that the required condition is that your linear functions are linearly independent and then you just pick a linear transformation which sends them to (some subset of) the standard coordinate functions (if I am misinterpreting, my apologies). Can you give a concrete example of the sort of thing you want to have happen?

Comment: The main problem of assuming that the linear functions are linearly independent is that my set of linear functions are never, in practice, linearly independent. The interesting case is actually when the linear functional are linearly dependent.

Comment: An interesting problem would be to find a desingularization for the set of linear functionals $f_1(x) = a^{T} x,\ f_2 (x) = b^{T} x $ and $f_3 (x) =(t_1 a + t_2 b)^{T} x$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, with $\{a,b\}$ linearly independent set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $t_1, t_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. Note that the Theorem 2.1. says that it's possible to fund this desingularization.